# How to add Pie Chart with API-Data in my Android project

Tags: android, android-volley, pie-chart

I want to add a Pie Chart from server api data in my Android project. If I have 95 car,  60 bus,  106 bicycle and so on. Please let me know if anyone have any suggestions...

Comment: Check this chart library for android: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: checked but how to implement volley "api data" on any chart ? if you have any idea please share with me..

Answer (score 0):

Just follow some basic tutorial and you need set data and refresh chart on response of your api.

Render an empty chart and call your request on **onCreate** method of activity:

```
initChart(); //init MPAndroidChart with empty data on this method.
callApi();
```

On your callApi method send your request to the server and do the following on **onResponse**:

```
pieChart.setData(data);
pieChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
pieChart.invalidate();
```

[Tutorial example for charting](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-pie-chart-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial)

> Try something and share your code with us then we can help you easier.